# Blueimp jQuery file upload, how to send extra input field along with files while upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, struts2

Am using jquery-fileupload.js. I want to send another text field along with each files while uploading the files. Can anyone help how or where to append the text field while uploading files? Am not very clear in jquery-fileupload.js code.

```
_I have added the text field inside_

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <!-- ... -->
       <td>
             <s:textarea name="imgDesc{%=i%}" cols="10" rows="2" theme="simple"/>
      </td>
        <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

---

Now am getting files in Struts2 action. I also want to get a text field while uploading the files.
    Please help.

Comment: Can you post your JS code or a snippet?

Comment: Am implementing basic ui in blueimp for that the basic js is jquery-fileupload.js which is called in main.js. Do you want the jquery-fileupload.js file.I referred "https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data" but am not clear.

Comment: I was referring to the code which you have written to call the file upload function in javascript. Did you want to add a custom parameter while sending the file request?

Comment: I want to add a textarea field which has description for the added file while uploading the file.

Comment: sorry in the question i mention as "to get text field". but i want to add text field/ textarea for the file description that to be upload along with the file.

Answer (score 0):

I just added extra field(text/ textarea) inside "" just like the code in my question. I can able to get the extra in action class with any change in jquery.fileupload.js. I think

---

```
formData: function (form) {
                return form.serializeArray();
            },
```

---

will handle the process.